# RequireConfirmedAccount in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity

In `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInOptions`: what is `RequireConfirmedAccount` and why is it different to `RequireConfirmedEmail`?

What does it mean for an account to be *confirmed*?

Answer (score 6):

`RequireConfirmedAccount` is a new higher level option that if set will use the `IUserConfirmation` service to determine if a user is confirmed and hence allowed to logged in.

The default implementation of this, just uses `RequireConfirmedEmail`, but the idea is this is the new extensibility point for developers to decide whether a user is considered confirmed and able to log in.

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/13206